# Using background-positioning bottom properties

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put background image at end of page ( at bottom bar) but key word bottom does not work, if I use like 900px or 55em it does work but in inspect element shows in middle of page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Website</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body{                                                         
        background: url('google2.png') no-repeat center bottom;
      } 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the `body` full width? If not, make it using `html, body {height: 100%;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `body` doesn't seem to take up the full height. So in your CSS, add this:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```